# Aggregate a column by only some keys in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
k1     k2     k3     v1     v2
foo    bar    baz    20     40
foo    bar    baz    10     30
foo    bar    baz    5      20
foo    bar    qux    10     20
foo    bar    qux    10     30
foo    bar    qux    15     20
bar    baz    foo    10     15
bar    baz    foo    20     35
bar    baz    foo    10     40
```

What I want to do is basically aggregate (sum) v1 by all three of the k* columns but only aggregate v2 by k1 and k2, so I end up with something like this:

```
k1     k2     k3     v1     v2
foo    bar    baz    35     160
foo    bar    qux    35     160
bar    baz    foo    40     90
```

In other words, in the aggregated version v2 basically ignores the presence of k3 and just has the total across k1 and k2 in both rows. I can't seem to get it to accomplish this no matter what I try, but I'm sure I'm just missing something. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's no way around doing groupby twice. Then join.

```
In [22]: df1 = df.groupby(['k1', 'k2', 'k3'])['v1'].sum()

In [23]: df2 = df.groupby(['k1', 'k2'])['v2'].sum()

In [24]: df1.reset_index().join(df2, on=['k1', 'k2'])
Out[24]:
    k1   k2   k3  v1   v2  
0  bar  baz  foo  40   90  
1  foo  bar  baz  35  160 
2  foo  bar  qux  35  160
```

Comment: I think that's going to get me the rest of the way. Awesome, thanks!